# Correlation matrix for subset of columns from a multiple imputation dataset

Tags: r, r-mice

I am using the `mice` package in `R` to do multiple imputations of a dataset with a large amount of missingness.  There are variables in the raw dataset that are important for the imputation process, and for later analyses.  However, I want to create a correlation matrix using `cor()` without including some of the variables.  Normally, for a simple dataset `x`, `cor(x[,3:7])` would yield the correlation matrix for columns 3 through 7.  If `x` is a `mids` object created by the `mice` function, one would normally use `with` to perform a repeated analysis to create a `mira` object, and then use `pool` to create a `mipo` pooled outcomes object.  However, the second element of `with` is supposed to be a formula that references the columns of the dataset, and that is not the kind of input that goes into `cor()`.  If `x` is a `mids` object, `cor(x[,3:7])` does not work, and neither does `with(x, cor(x[,3:7]))`.

How can I created a pooled correlation matrix for a subset of the variables from a multiple imputation data set?

```
#reproducible example
x = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10))  #create random data
x[9:10,] = NA #add missingness
x.mice = mice(x)  #make imputed data set
cor(x.mice[,3:7]) #doesn't work
with(x.mice, cor(x.mice[,3:7])) #doesn't work
with(x.mice[,3:7], cor()) #doesn't work
```

Comment: Please consider adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your question: it will help us a lot helping you.

Comment: Good point, Vincent Guillemot.  I added one to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: If you name the columns in your data , its probably easier to work with. So use `x = setNames(x, letters[1:10])` at the relevant place (before calling mice) and then this should work `with(x.mice, cor(cbind(a,b)))`

Comment: But as another thought, as there is not a `pool` method (unless you use `lm` i guess), it may be easier just to loop through the `complete` datasets... `lapply(1:5, function(ii) cor(complete(x.mice, ii)[3:7]))`

Comment: To pool the results, I would just take the *mean* matrix, which is coincidentally also a correlation matrix. If all the matrices are in a list `L`, do `Reduce("+",L)/5` to obtain the pooled correlation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. The newly added package "miceadds" adds very useful functionality to the mice package.

Specifically, for your problem, look up the function *micombine.cor* which does inference for correlations and covariances for multiply imputed
datasets.

Eg:

```
library(missForest)
library(mice)
library(miceadds)

#Get the data
data <- iris

#introduce missings
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.1)


#imputedata
imputed     <-mice(iris.mis, m = 5, maxit = 5, method = "pmm")

#correlations for the first three variables (package miceadds) 
correlations<- miceadds::micombine.cor(mi.res=iris.mis, variables = c(1:3))

#and because i am a psychologist and don't like scientific coding... 
old_school<-format(correlations$p, scientific=FALSE)
correlations["p_value"] <- NA; correlations$p_value <- old_school; 
correlations
```